Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 6025 (line 1 column 6026)
I'm trying to view code coverage using my vscode but after running test if I enter in the class I was testing, I have this error and I can't see the code coverage and the percentage anymore.
Thx in advance.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the tour and read How to Ask. You will need to edit your question to include more details.

I'm actually still having issues with this (since last week) as I've really tried everything. My colleagues solution is this however: update salesforce > sf update > exit visual studio code completely once update is complete using task manager / restart PC This was their solution and it worked. However it hasn't worked for me yet, so still waiting for another solution. But give it a try!

This is a known issue. You can review the comments to find a temporary solution.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/5534 Downgrading the extensions to v60.7.0, works for me.

There is a bug with the new version of the extension
Downgrade the apex extension from 68.0 to 67.0 and restart visual studio.
Then rerun the test(s)
This solved the problem for me


I think I found the error, but I think it's given from the plugin. Looking at the highlighted file in the screen above I removed all the irrelevant commas at the final element of a list.

Thanks for your response ! It works well But i'm obliged to always refactor the json file by deleting the comma and this is so hard !

I'm still searching a solution to save the coverage json without trailing commas.

I solved downgrading Apex extension to v60.7.0 as suggested from Jair. Thanks a lot

Hello Nicola Thanks you it works very well
